# Определить первый запуск программы после загрузки Windows

Tags: c++, winapi

Какие простые способы существуют под Windows определить, что моя программа, после загрузки Windows, уже запускалась?

Comment: Сохранять где-нибудь время запуска. При запуске читать это значение и сравнивать его со временем загрузки Windows (через консоль можно получить, например, через `wmic os get lastbootuptime`, наверняка где-то есть и соответствующая функция WinApi)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Думал об этом, но показался данный способ не эстетичным, и, подозревал, что должны существовать более элегантные способы, как предложил ниже KoVadim!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть один трюк, который решает эту проблему - связанный вопрос на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717916/find-out-if-computer-rebooted-since-the-last-time-my-program-ran/1719583#1719583).

```
if (GlobalFindAtom ("MySecretName") == 0)
{
  // нас запустили первый раз! запомним это
  GlobalAddAtom ("MySecretName");
}
```

суть - есть такая глобальная таблица атомов - пяям такой себе системный аналог глобальной переменной типа близкого к `std::set<const char*>`. И есть возможность [добавить в него свою строку](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globaladdatoma), [удалить](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-deleteatom) и [проверить, а есть ли она в списке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globalfindatoma). При перезагрузке этот список очищается.

Comment: Сердечно благодарю! Ещё не пробовал, но уверен, это то, что мне нужно!